# How to update the state in react?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'd like to update the state and display the current state in a React Fragment inside a method. I'm updating the state in reserve method and I'd like to display the new value on a button click. I was trying to do that in the span in fetchData() method but when I click the button, I don't see the updated value. Below is the screen shot of the application and code.
[image]

```
class BooksComponent extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            booksData: [],
            offset: 0,
            perPage: 3,
            currentPage: 0,
        }
        this.reserve = this.reserve.bind(this)
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this)
    }

    fetchData(){
        axios.get('/library')
          .then(res => {
            const booksData = res.data
            const slice = booksData.slice(this.state.offset, this.state.offset + this.state.perPage)
            const books = slice.map(book => 
            <React.Fragment key={book.id}>
                <p>{book.id} - {book.title} - {book.author}</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.reserve(book.id)}>Reserve {book.quantity}</button>
                <span>{this.state.booksData.quantity}</span>
            </React.Fragment>)

            this.setState({ 
                pageCount: Math.ceil(booksData.length / this.state.perPage),
                books })
          })
    }

    handlePageClick = (e) => {
        const selectedPage = e.selected;
        const offset = selectedPage * this.state.perPage;

        this.setState({
            currentPage: selectedPage,
            offset: offset
        }, () => {
            this.fetchData()
        });
    };
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData()
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
              {this.state.books}
            <ReactPaginate
                    previousLabel={"prev"}
                    nextLabel={"next"}
                    breakLabel={"..."}
                    breakClassName={"break-me"}
                    pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}/>
          </div>
        )
    }

    reserve(id) {
        console.log("clicked")
        this.setState({
            booksData: this.state.booksData.map(item => {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    return { ...item, quantity: (item.quantity - 1) >= 0 ? (item.quantity - 1) : 0};
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            })
        })
    }
}


export default BooksComponent
```

Comment: Avoid storing JSX in the state, and instead, store the data with which to generate the JSX in the `render` function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store jsx in your state, store the data and let React handle the render, so, just do this in your `fetchData` function

```
this.setState({ 
  pageCount: Math.ceil(booksData.length / this.state.perPage),
  books
})
```

and in your render

```
<div className="App">
  {this.state.books.map(book => 
    <React.Fragment key={book.id}>
      <p>{book.id} - {book.title} - {book.author}</p>
      <button onClick={() => this.reserve(book.id)}>Reserve {book.quantity}</button>
      <span>{this.state.booksData.quantity}</span>
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
  <ReactPaginate...
</div>
```

This will re-render when the state changes and will display the correct value

Comment: Thank you! Where would I slice the data? @ludwiguer

Comment: In the fetchData function

Comment: I sliced the data in the fetchData() function and moved the jsx into render. It throws back the error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". What is happening here? It is from the second line in the above jsx you mentioned.

Comment: Because the first render the state is not set until componenDidMount is called, you can solve it easily by putting a guard in your code, change the second  line for this `this.state.books && this.state.books.map(book =>`